# While loop end when i gets infinity close to zero?

Tags: algorithm

So I was wondering the time complexity of the following problem. The correct solution says it's O(logN); I understand this if this loop terminates. But since we are only halve i so theoretically i can get really close to 0, but never ends?!

```
int a = 0, i = N;
        while (i > 0) {
            a += i;
            i /= 2;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the loop will actually end. Since `i` is an `int`, when you halve `i` you are performing integer division. The result of this division will get rounded down to the nearest integer.
For example:

```
int i=3;
int j= i/2;
// j really is 1.5, but we're performing integer division
// so the result will be j =1
```

If we consider a run of your program for `N=5`, we have:

First iteration:

```
i=5;
i = i/2 = 5/2 = 2.5 = 2; //Round 2.5 down
```

Second iteration:

```
i=2
i = i/2 = 2/2 = 1;
```

Third iteration:

```
i=1;
i = i/2 = 1/2 = 0.5 = 0; //Round 0.5 down, loop finishes
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to keep in mind that you're dividing an `int`, not a floating-point value, so there is no fractional component. Instead, any remainder will simply be discarded. So once you get down to 1, half of that is 0.5, and since you take the integer part only, you will have 0. So therefore, this will eventually finish.

For example, if you started with `10`:

`10 / 2` is `5`

`5 / 2` is `2` with a remainder of `1`—remainder is discarded—`i` is `2`

`2 / 2` is `1`

`1 / 2` is `0` with a remainder of `1`—remainder is discarded—`i` is `0`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using integer arithmetic, i does go to 0.
Here's an interactive example using [picoc](https://github.com/zsaleeba/picoc)

```
$ picoc -i
starting picoc v2.1
picoc> #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
picoc> int a=0, i=10;
int a=0, i=10;
picoc> a += i; i /= 2; printf("a=%d i=%d\n",a,i);
a += i; i /= 2; printf("a=%d i=%d\n",a,i);
a=10 i=5
picoc> a += i; i /= 2; printf("a=%d i=%d\n",a,i);
a += i; i /= 2; printf("a=%d i=%d\n",a,i);
a=15 i=2
picoc> a += i; i /= 2; printf("a=%d i=%d\n",a,i);
a += i; i /= 2; printf("a=%d i=%d\n",a,i);
a=17 i=1
picoc> a += i; i /= 2; printf("a=%d i=%d\n",a,i);
a += i; i /= 2; printf("a=%d i=%d\n",a,i);
a=18 i=0
```

Your loop would have terminated at this point.